# Why the below query in elasticsearch does not work?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have test data shown below.

```
{
   "SequenceLocation":{
   "Assembly":"GPR7",
   "Chr": "10",
   "start": 1111
    }
}
```

Whenever I fired query like below it returns me proper values.

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
      { 
        "term" : {
          "SequenceLocation.Chr": "10"
        }
      }
      ]
    }
  }
  }
```

But when I changes query to

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
      { 
        "term" : {
          "SequenceLocation.Assembly": "GPR7"
        }
      }
      ]
    }
  }
  }
```

It does not return me any hits from Elasticsearch. Could you please explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have wrong mapping for `SequenceLocation.Assembly`. Default analyzer splits `GPR7.p10` into two tokens `gpr7` and `p10`.

According to documentation [term query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) doesn't analyze your query, so you are asking elasticsearch for `GPR7.p10` but it is indexed as tokens `gpr7` and `p10`. So it can't match.

You should recreate index with [mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#mappings) set to `"index" : "not_analyzed"` for `SequenceLocation.Assembly` field.

Comment: I already tried with data for assembly without any '.' in it. Still I am facing the issue :(. I will update my question so that it will not mislead the users

Comment: The answer is still valid. The (default) [StandardAnalyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) generates the Token `gpr7` (lowercase) while the term query matches only the exact terms. Since `GPR7` is different from `gpr7`, there is no match. Besides changing the mapping as suggested by @vhyza, you could also use a [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), which _does_ analyze the query text.

Comment: As @knutwalker said, `StandardAnalyzer` lowercases your input. You can check how would be field indexed by using [analyze api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html). For example: `curl localhost:9200/INDEX_WITH_MAPPING/_analyze?text=GPR7&field= SequenceLocation.Assembly&pretty` shows you `gpr7` if `SequenceLocation.Assembly` is defined with `standard` analyzer.